# Can we consider compact sets of Riemannian manifolds as ones of closed Rimanninan manifolds?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a $C^\infty$ Riemannian manifold of $n$ dimensional and suppose $\emptyset\neq K \stackrel{\mathrm{compact}}{\subset} M$. 
Then are there any neiborhood $\Omega\stackrel{\mathrm{open}}\subset M$ of $K$, closed $C^\infty$ Riemannian manifold $(N,h)$ of $n$ dimensional and isometric embedding $f:\Omega\to N$ ?

Comment: Yes. Compactify $M$ and edit the metric far away from $K$ to get something Riemannian.

Comment: @WillieWong: I don't really understand your comment, since there's no reason that $M$ should embed into a compact manifold; eg take $M$ to be an infinite genus surface. But certainly $K$ is contained in a compact submanifold (w/ boundary), but why should we always be able to choose this submanifold so that we can cap off the boundary with a manifold?

Comment: @MikeMiller: I meant $\Omega$ in my first comment; sorry. (Of course that requires using that $K$ is compact to guarantee that you get a manifold.) // And it is a comment not an answer because the construction _is_ technical . (Jack Lee's answer below is great and short; but there's a lot of background behind the various Propositions he uses. I don't want to reproduce all that.)

Comment: @WillieWong: Sure, I was just checking I wasn't missing something obvious.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. Here's a sketch of a proof. (The theorem references are from my *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*, 2nd ed.)

First, let $f\colon M\to \mathbb R$ be a smooth exhaustion function, i.e., a function whose sublevel sets $M_c = f^{-1}((-\infty,c])$ are compact for all $c\in\mathbb R$. (Such a function exists by Prop. 2.28.) Because the sets $U_c = f^{-1}((-\infty,c))$ form an increasing open cover of $K$, there is some $C$ such that $K\subseteq U_C$.

By Sard's theorem (Thm. 6.10), there is some $c>C$ that is a regular value of $f$, and then $M_c$ is a regular domain in $M$ whose interior contains $K$ (Prop. 5.47). Since a regular domain is, in particular, a smooth manifold with boundary, we can form its double $D(M_c)$, which is a compact manifold without boundary containing a diffeomorphic copy of $M_c$ (Example 9.32). Using a partition of unity, it is straightforward to extend the given Riemannian metric on $M_c$ to a smooth Riemannian metric on all of $D(M_c)$.